# Extracting specific values to new raster in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, file-geodatabase, extract-by-mask

I have a map with data stored in file geodatabase (gdb) format. As I opened it in ArcGIS 10, I see that it has data for 12 years, each year encoded in different color.

How do I create 12 different maps from this one big dataset, when in the attribute table there is only an objectid column, a value column (12 levels, corresponds to each year), and the count number column (the number of cells that has data for each year)?

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Spatial Analyst is necessary for most raster tasks in ArcGIS beyond simple display and clipping.

If you have that, then you can use [Extract by Attributes](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z00000029000000) to create new rasters of just one value. It would be the value from the original raster though, and you'd have to [Reclassify](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z000000sr000000) it to 1 or 0.

You can use Reclassify directly to generate a new raster and map the input values to new ones. So you could map 4 to 1 and all other values to 0.

You can also use a Con statement in the [Raster Calculator](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Raster_Calculator/009z000000z7000000/) to generate a binary output. I believe the expression would be `Con("raster" = 4, 1, 0)` (which is `con(condition, true, false)`).

All of these solutions have to be run once for each value you want to extract.